# Having Issue on Accessing Singleton Database Object In PHP MVC

Tags: php

I am having trouble on accessing to an instance of a singleton class in PHP MVC. Basically the MVC looks like

[image]

First of all I have included and instantiated objects in the `init.php` as

```
// include objects
include('app/Database.php');
include('app/models/m_template.php');
include('app/models/m_categories.php');

// create objects
$tdatabase = new Database();
$Template = new Template();
$Categories = new Categories();
```

and in `m_categories.php` I tried to use the `$tdatabase` object as:

```
<?php

class Categories {

    private $db_table = 'category';

    function __construct() { }

    public function get_categories() {
        $data = array();
        $res = $tdatabase->query("SELECT * FROM " . $this->db_table . " ORDER BY name");

        foreach ($res as $dataRow):
            $data[] = array('id' => $dataRow['id'],
                'name' => $dataRow['name'],
                'img' => $dataRow['img'],
                'alt' => $dataRow['alt'],
            );

        endforeach;
        return $data;
    }
}
```

and finally in `index.php` I have:

```
<?php
include('app/init.php');

echo '<pre>';
 print_r($Categories->get_categories());
echo '</pre>';
```

but I am getting following errors:

[image]

can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can fix this?

Update 1:

[image]

Update 2

[image]

Comment: `Categories` object doesn't have any information about outside variables. You sholud pass `Database` object to your `Categories` object e.g. by constructor or by method parameter.

Comment: Why don't you paste text instead of images of your notices? It makes it very very hard to read such small print.

Comment: Sorry Fred I tought it's better to put every thing there, however, the image can be enlarge br Right Click-> Open Image in New Tab,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Categories` object doesn't have any information about outside variables. You sholud pass `Database` object to your `Categories` object e.g. by constructor or by method parameter.

init.php

```
$tdatabase = new Database();
$Template = new Template();
$Categories = new Categories($tdatabase);
```

m_categories.php

```
class Categories {
    protected $database;
    private $db_table = 'category';

    function __construct($database) {
         $this->database = $database;
    }

    public function get_categories() {
        $data = array();
        $res = $this->database->query("SELECT * FROM " . $this->db_table . " ORDER BY name");
        // (...)
    }
```

Comment: @Behseini Are you sure you update both your files `init.php` and `m_categories`? I made a typo in variables names, I fix it up, so now should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

your variable tdatabase is out of scope. you either need to pass it into the function, or set it as a class member variable in the constructor or via a setter

i.e.

```
public function get_categories(Database $tdatabase) {
        $data = array();
        $res = $tdatabase->query("SELECT * FROM " . $this->db_table . " ORDER BY name");
```

I often see code like this though, and I (almost) always recommend, especially for new projects that you use the model/mapper pattern because it is more easily extensible and is more maintainable. See here for an example:

[OOP PHP PDO My First Project , Am I doing right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975687/oop-php-pdo-my-first-project-am-i-doing-right/28975886#28975886)

Comment: Thanks Zak but I am getting a new error now Please check the update 1